# Default values for optional command line arguments

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a socket programming task to build a client/server chat. My code works when I type `3` value in terminal, but the problem is that I can't think of a way to put them all as an optional arguments and put some default value to work in any kind of that's example below,

1. `./Client`
2. `./Client username`
3. `./Client username portNumber`
4. `./Client username portNumber serverAddress`

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    connection_info connection;
    fd_set file_descriptors;

    if (argc =! 4)
      {
          fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s <IP> <port> <Name>\n", argv[0]);
          exit (1);
      }


         connect_to_server(&connection, argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
}
```

Regarding the default value, just I need the username to be "Anynamous" and the ip is "localhost" while the port is 3000

Comment: When `(argc == 3 )`, how would you like to call `connect_to_server()`?  What default value would you like for _serverAddress_?

Comment: `char username[100] = "fooy"; if(argc >= 2) strncpy(username, argv[1], 99);`

Comment: I changed the tags on your question: Just because your program happens to use threads does not mean that it's appropriate to use the "multithreading" tag. You should only use that tag if there's something you don't understand about multithreading in particular. Same goes for "unix" tag and "chat" tag. Your question here is about how a C program can make sense of its command-line arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SolomonSlow for your feedback regarding the question .. That is first time here, it will be better next time.

Comment: Really appreciate your reply @chux-ReinstateMonica , regarding the default value just I want the username to be "Anynamous" and the ip is "localhost" while the port is 3000.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, hope to help me on the 3 Argument as I mention before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the username to be "Anynamous" and the ip is "localhost" while the port is 3000

Set up for those default values and change them if enough arguments passed.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char *username = "Anynamous"; // Or maybe "Anonymous" 
  const char *ip = "localhost";
  int port = 3000;

  if (argc >= 2) username = argv[1];
  if (argc >= 3) ip = argv[2];
  if (argc >= 4) port = atoi(argv[3]);  // Could add some conversion checking here.

  connection_info connection;
  connect_to_server(&connection, username, ip, port);
  fd_set file_descriptors;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I used your code it show me than "Segmentation fault (core dumped)
" , so dont know where is the problem till now. But when I insert the data directly to  the command line it's work correctly.

Comment: @unknown Best to post a [mcve].

Comment: See the full source code above, I just add my full code that I have been used. @chux - Reinstate Monica

Comment: @chux-reinstate-monica

Comment: @unknown Not quite minimal.  Hmmm `connect_to_server (connection_info * connection, char *address, char *port, char *name)` needs 3 `char *`, adjust code for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I fix it .. @chux - Reinstate Monica